# My markers are not displayed React leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

The goal is to displayed marker on map.

I don't understand why my markers are not displayed

I use react-leaflet

The response is okay but nothing is displayed

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXgH0.png)

[My map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ9Gu.jpg)

Import

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, ScaleControl } from 'react-leaflet';
import tileLayer from '../util/tileLayer';
import L from "leaflet";
import 'leaflet-fullscreen/dist/Leaflet.fullscreen.js';
import 'leaflet-fullscreen/dist/leaflet.fullscreen.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import newMarker from "../data/asset/pin.png";
import axios from 'axios'
```

center of first view

```
const center = [46.227638, 2.213749];
```

Icon

```
const pointerIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: newMarker,
  iconSize: [50, 58], // size of the icon
  iconAnchor: [20, 58], // changed marker icon position
});
```

Markers

```
const MyMarkers = ({ data }) => {
  return data.map(({ lat, lng }, index) => (
    <Marker
      key={index}
      position={{ lat, lng }}
      icon={pointerIcon}
    >
    </Marker>
  ));
}
```

get data with useEffect, async await & axios

```
const MapWrapper = () => {

  useEffect( async () => {

    markers = (await componentDataMarkers()).data
    console.log(markers);
  }, [])
  const componentDataMarkers = async () => await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/plane/latlong`)
  var markers = []
```

React Leaflet component

```
  return (
    <MapContainer
    fullscreenControl={true}
    center={center}
    zoom={13}
    scrollWheelZoom={true}
    >

      <TileLayer {...tileLayer} />

      <MyMarkers data={markers} />
      <ScaleControl imperial={false} />
    </MapContainer>
  )
}

export default MapWrapper;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return data.map(({ lat, lng }, index) => (
    <Marker
      key={index}
      position={[ lat, lng ]} // array here
      icon={pointerIcon}
    >
    </Marker>
  ));
```

Here, why do you extract lat and lng from an array with key 0 and 1 ?
**You can't use extract { lat, lng } from array**, only from object with lat and lng keys.

Can you console.log the lat and lng and see if you have the data here or undefined ?

Comment: in log : undefined lat home.js:40
undefined lng

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2022/19/5/1652430341-code-gspvyzj482.png

Comment: Yes, because you try to extract data in map like object, but it's an array.
data.map(({ lat, lng }, index) you can't to that, try :
data.map((value, index)

And use lat like value[0] and lng like value[1]

Comment: in log : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2022/19/5/1652430510-es1yz4phs8.png

Comment: ok and How can I do ? edit : ok  i'll try

Comment: Just look, i've edited my comment

Comment: Try console.log all value, and you can watch and find out.

Comment: Like this it still doesn't work 
return data.map((value, index) => (
      
    <Marker
      key={index}
      position={[value[0], value[1]]}
      icon={pointerIcon}
    >
    </Marker>

Comment: What value does if you console.log(value) ?

Comment: console.log(markers.value, "value") in mapWrapper() undefind

Comment: Nop, it's normal markers.value doesn't exist.
In the .map, if you console.log(value), what do you have ?
Exemple : 
const MyMarkers = ({ data }) => {
  return data.map((value, index) => (
    {console.log(value)}
    <Marker
      key={index}
      position={value}
      icon={pointerIcon}
    >
    </Marker>
  ));
}

Comment: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2022/19/5/1652445726-code-icdrnxhr0f.png

I have an other idea its not about state ?

Comment: I don't think. I'm sure about the fact you try to use 'data' as an object, and not an array of array.
Try use a for boucle in place of map.

Answer (score 1):

`Marker` position is type `[lat, lng]` & NOT `{lat, lng}`. Example -

```
<Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]} />
```

**Update**: Your `data` object is an `array` of `arrays`. `map` function seems to be incorrect. It needs to be like `markers.map((marker, index) =>`

Working sample that you can try at [live editor](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker/) -

```
const center = [51.505, -0.09]
const markers = [[51.505, -0.10], [51.505, -0.09], [51.505, -0.08]];
const MyMarkers = ({ data }) => {
    return data.map((marker, index) => {
     return (
     <Marker key={index} position={marker}>
      <Popup>
        Marker <br /> Popup.
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
     ); 
     });
}
render(
  <MapContainer center={center} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
   <MyMarkers data={markers} />
  </MapContainer>,
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Nothing is displayed even when doing what you recommended

Comment: Please share the `data` object.

Comment: here : 
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2022/19/5/1652428349-firefox-64sfbyanv4.png

Comment: `data.map` is incorrect. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I do what you recommend and that still not work

Comment: @Fractalys_sync: if you can, try to avoid statements of the form "it does not work". That will usually be regarded as the least informative fault report possible. Try to describe _how_ it doesn't work, or what looks odd, or whether you have any errors, etc. If you provide no information then your helper has to do all the work asking you to check various things - supply that in the first instance if you can.